# Cancelling an edit

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I just edited a question, but apparently someone else edited and submitted and edit whilst I was doing mine and that was accepted and, in all fairness, it looks better than my edit. Is it possible for me to "cancel" my edit or take it off the peer review and so we can just leave the question as it is?

EDIT: So...??

EDIT 2: I was going through my old Meta posts and I've noticed that this feature still hasn't been implemented, despite what looks like a positive reaction. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: I like this idea, I have often had the same problem.

Comment: I also had the same problem.

Comment: Often I need to withdraw editions as well. This would save time for the reviewers and would improve the dynamic of the questions, why is no one implementing this?

Comment: If you propose a some change to the current functionality, why not tagging this post as a ([meta-tag:feature-request])?

Comment: Some related post on meta.SE (both of them feature request): [How can I cancel an edit I made on another user's question or answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/80933) and [Why can't I cancel an edit action?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/123355)

Comment: And similar posts on this meta: 
[Undo edits just suggested](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/4969),
[Withdraw my own edit suggestion](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/20922) and [Can we reject our own edit?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/24914)

Comment: You might also notice that this is tagged as [support] rather than [feature-request], so there's no reason the developers would have this post on their radar to even know about your feature request.